# Excecute macro on any desired workbook/spreadsheet using a command button

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro workbook to be used by my accounting department.  The macro workbook contains dynamic macros that can be used for a number of different reasons by different users.  To take it a step further, I have created a front menu in the macro workbook that has a command button assigned for each  macro and a description in the cell next to the command button of that macro.

I would like for the user to click on the command button of the macro they desire and then select the spreadsheet from a different workbook for the macro to be executed on.  Below is one of the sample macro's.  In essence, I'm trying to find out how I can avoid a user having to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> to select and run a macro housed in the macro workbook by allowing a user to select a command button of their choice.

The Steps would be:

1. The user will download a report or will have a workbook open that they would like to execute a macro from the general macro workbook for the department
2. The user will open the general macro workbook saved in one of the shared drives
3. The user will click on the command button of the macro they would like to execute shown on the front menu.  This will trigger the macro to execute but nothing will happen until the user toggles through and selects the workbook and spreadsheet to execute the macro in.
4. User selects desired workbook and spreadsheet to confirm to apply the macro to and the macro will execute

I am stuck on how to build the logic to link step 3 to step 4.

```
Sub fill_in()
'Fills in blank cells with populated cells above
'could help with filling in GL's for a set number of rows below
'could help with filling in Property IDs or Resident IDs, etc.


Dim col As String
col = InputBox("Enter Column Letter to find Last Row")

Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim StartCol As String
    Dim EndCol As String

    StartRow = InputBox("Enter Beginning Row # for Range")
    StartCol = InputBox("Enter Beginning Column Letter for Range")
    EndCol = InputBox("Enter Last Column Letter for Range")

Dim Rg As Range
Set Rg = Range(Cells(StartRow, StartCol), Cells(lrow, EndCol))

'Fill data for each cell below
Dim MyCounter As Long
MyCounter = 0
    For Each r In Rg
        On Error Resume Next
        If r.Value = "" Then
            r.Value = r.Offset(-1, 0).Value
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello So here is what I got for you in each one of you're buttons put this code than switch out the sub names for example I put your fill_in sub in this code just change it out

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet


Dim YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox As String
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox("Would you like to run the macro on " & wb.Name & "?", vbYesNo, "Where to run marco?")
If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes Then
wb.Activate
With wb
For Each sheet In wb.Worksheets
YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = MsgBox("Would you like to run the macro on worksheet " & sheet.Name & "?", vbYesNo, "Where to run marco?")
If YesOrNoAnswerToMessageBox = vbYes Then
sheet.Activate

'Put sub name here
fill_in

End If
Next sheet
End With
End If
Next wb
```

Comment: All you should have to do is Change the sub names out Let me me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hahaha!  This is amazing work.  Thank you very much.  I figured it would fall along the lines of this but I was hitting a mental road block.  Thank you very much.  I think this will make it easier for everyone that hasn't had a lot of macro exposure.  It makes perfect sense.  I tested this out and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well I am glade I could help